# How to enable spark.history.fs.cleaner in Spark2?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, ambari

I've got `spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled = true` for both my Spark2 and Spark configuration. It works for keeping /spark-history/ clean, but fails to do anything for /spark2-history. Any thoughts on why it's not working?

Comment: Is this really `spark.history.fs.cleaner=enabled` (with the `=`)? It should rather be `spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled=true`. How do you set it?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. The key is spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled. The value is true.

Comment: How do you check that the value is turned on?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski go into ambari and see that it's set to "enabled"

Answer (score 0):

`spark.history.fs.cleaner.enabled` Spark property controls a task that periodically cleans event logs on disk.

In your question it's `spark.history.fs.cleaner=enabled` so I think the issue is with the `=` character.

---

The other `spark.history.fs.cleaner.interval` Spark property (with `1d` default value) controls how often the cleaner checks for event logs to delete. Make sure that it's often enough.

Comment: It was just a typo. THe original problem still exists. My interval is set to 1d. Max age 7d. It seems to have no effect on /spark2-history/ folder contents.